# laravel api max length

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-api

This code fetches all the data in the table in the database, but I want to set a maximum limit, for example, it fetches only 4 columns from the table so that it does not load all the columns in the table

```
   'productes' => productModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'productes' => productModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(20)->get(['id',...])
```

Try this. But I'm highly recommended you read laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

`limit` is the count of rows that will be fetched from DB and
`get` will fetch columns that you passed in the array